# How should I Private DM my user after they send a command? (Discord Python)

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I am coding a python discord program, and I'm very new to this. I tried a few answers to Private DMs, but none of them seemed to work. I can't tell if I am doing anything wrong. I would like any user/a user with a role to say a command, eg .gen and the bot sends dm.

My code:

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from random import randint

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', description='Generates accounts')
x=1
spotifynum = 0
spotifyvisnum = 1

with open("spotify.txt") as f:
    spot = f.readlines()
    spot = [x.strip() for x in spot]

with open("spotify.txt") as f:
    spot = f.readlines()
    spot = [x.strip() for x in spot]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(("-")*40)
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(("-")*40)

@bot.command()
async def hello():
    await bot.say('Hello!')

@bot.command()
async def gen():
    await ctx.author.send("hi")





bot.run('private_code')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the docs for rewrite, but probably using async code. You need to use `await bot.send(dest, message)` to send messages in async